# Load Player's saved Position and Scene with Playerprefs

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a game, and I am trying to load the player's position and saved scene when he clicks the load button. I finished making the part to load the saved scene, however i can't figure out how to load the player's saved position.

```
public class Save : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Menu_Script MS;
    private Vector3 CordsStored;
    public Transform PlayerLocation;
    private float X;
    private float Z;
    private float Y;
    public int SceneIndex;
    
    private void Start() {}
    
    public void SaveScene()
    {
        MS.ClickSound.Play();
        SceneIndex = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex;
        
        X = PlayerLocation.position.x;

        Z = PlayerLocation.position.z;

        Y = PlayerLocation.position.y;
          

        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Player_Z_Cord",Convert.ToInt32(Z));

        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Player_X_Cord", Convert.ToInt32(X));

        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Player_Y_Cord", Convert.ToInt32(Y));

        CordsStored.z = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Player_Z_Cord");

        CordsStored.x = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Player_X_Cord");

        CordsStored.y = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Player_Y_Cord");

        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("SavedScene", SceneIndex);

        PlayerPrefs.Save();

        Debug.Log(SceneIndex + " " +  X + " "  + Z + " " + Y);
    }
    
    public async void LoadExactSceneAndPos()
    {
        MS.ClickSound.Play();//click sound
        await Task.Delay(100);
        SceneManager.LoadScene(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("SavedScene"));
        PlayerLocation.position = CordsStored;
    }
```

This script i tried doesn't work, it only loads the saved scene, but not the saved position. Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1):

```
SceneManager.LoadScene(PlayerPrefs.GetInt("SavedScene"));
PlayerLocation.position = CordsStored;
```

Everytime a scene loads, it creates a new set of game-object and the relevant components with it.
The problem with that right now is that the code is still executing in the old `Save` object in the previous scene, and assigning values to the old `PlayerLocation` in the previous scene.

One way to resolve this is to load the player's position on start instead, like so:

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour {
  // ...
  
  private void Start(){

    // Do a check to see if we just loaded from save
    if (justLoadedFromSave) {
      Vector3 savePos = Vector3.zero;

      // Fetch save position.
      savePos.z = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Player_Z_Cord");
      savePos.x = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Player_X_Cord");
      savePos.y = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Player_Y_Cord");

      // Set save position
      transform.position = savePos;
    }
  }
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, would this work if i added it to my playermovement script?

Comment: @CaptainW It would work as long as you are changing the position of whatever you are targeting.